# Removing keys in pair form from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have a python dictionary, tDosDict, like

```
{('M1', 'P1'): 6.0,
 ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0,
 ('M1', 'P3'): 4.0,
 ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0,
 ('M2', 'P2'): 6.0,
 ('M2', 'P3'): 5.0}
```

I am making some operations say,

```
valMin = min(tDosDict.values())
jobsR = [key for key in tDosDict if tDosDict[key] == valMin]
```

So I find that jobsR as `('M1', 'P3')`. Now I would like to remove the all the keys where `'P3'` appears from the tDosDict. So my updated keys will be

```
{('M1', 'P1'): 6.0,
 ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0,
 ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0,
 ('M2', 'P2'): 6.0,}
```

Again I shall make the same operation to drop the keys. I tried it in the following way, but it is not working

```
for key, value in tDosDict.items():
    if jobsR[0][1] in key[1]:
        tDosDict.pop(jobsR[0][1], None)
```

Kindly help me. Also I have to push it in the loop to iterate the process.

Comment: don't remove from `dict` but create new `dict` with elements which you want to keep. You could use `!=` instead of `==` when you create `jobsR` and you would have `tDosDict` without elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot edit an iterable while iterating over it. To get around this I made a list of the keys to remove, then removed them in a separate loop:

```
tDosDict = {('M1', 'P1'): 6.0,
 ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0,
 ('M1', 'P3'): 4.0,
 ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0,
 ('M2', 'P2'): 6.0,
 ('M2', 'P3'): 5.0}
 
valMin = min(tDosDict.values())
jobsR = [key for key in tDosDict if tDosDict[key] == valMin]

remove_list = []
for key, value in tDosDict.items():
    if jobsR[0][1] in key[1]:
        remove_list.append(key)
for item in remove_list:
    tDosDict.pop(item)
    
print(tDosDict)
```

Output:

```
{('M1', 'P1'): 6.0, ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0, ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0, ('M2', 'P2'): 6.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

An iteration like the following would achieve what you need - no need to iterate twice:

```
d = {('M1', 'P1'): 6.0, ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0, ('M1', 'P3'): 4.0, ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0, ('M2', 'P2'): 6.0, ('M2', 'P3'): 5.0}

{x: y for x, y in d.items() if x[0] in ["M1", "M2"] and x[1] != "P3"}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{('M1', 'P1'): 6.0, ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0, ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0, ('M2', 'P2'): 6.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove from `dict` but directly create new `dict` with elements which you want to keep.

Use `!=` instead of `==`

```
tDosDict = {key:val for key, val in tDosDict.items() if val != valMin}
```

---

```
tDosDict = {
    ('M1', 'P1'): 6.0,
    ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0,
    ('M1', 'P3'): 4.0,
    ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0,
    ('M2', 'P2'): 6.0,
    ('M2', 'P3'): 5.0
}

valMin = min(tDosDict.values())
#jobsR = [key for key in tDosDict if tDosDict[key] == valMin]

tDosDict = {key:val for key, val in tDosDict.items() if val != valMin}

print(tDosDict)
```

Comment: Thanks! How to continue this part through loop while I am appending the value

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do. What `loop`? What `values`? If you have new problem then you should describe it in new question on new page.

Answer (score 1):

This will also give desired output:

```
d = {
    ('M1', 'P1'): 6.0,
    ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0,
    ('M1', 'P3'): 4.0,
    ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0,
    ('M2', 'P2'): 6.0,
    ('M2', 'P3'): 5.0
}

valMin = min(d.values())
jobsR = [key for key in d if d[key] == valMin]

for key in [key for key in d if key[1] == jobsR[0][1] ]: del d[key]

print(d)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.